# what c++ norme i'm currently using?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, c++11

Recently I had faced compiling errors in a c++ code I wrote so I've been asked if I was using a C++11 compiler, but honestly I don't know how to check on my compiler version ! so any idea how to figure this out ??

Btw I'm using codeblocks as an IDE which includes the GCC compiler and GDB debugger from MinGW. also if I'm compiling my c++ code under Linux what command should I run to know my compiler version ?

Comment: Any reason for the downvote !!!!!!

Comment: The downvote tooltip reads "*This question does not show any research effort*".

Comment: Why was this marked as duplicate? He's asking a different question!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That can be a tricky question.  C++11 refers to a version of the
standard, not to a version of the compiler.  Different compilers, and
different versions of any given compiler, will typically implement a mix
of versions of the standard, at least for recent versions.  More or 
less, because any implementation of C++11 will be fairly new, and thus
probably fairly buggy.

Most compilers have options to output the version; many will output it
systematically in verbose mode.  For g++, try `g++ --version`.  Recent
versions of g++ do have some support for C++11, but you have to activate
it with `-std=c++0x` (rather than the usual `-std=c++03` or
`-std=c++98`).  As the name (`c++0x`, rather than `c++11`) indicates, it
is *not* truly C++11; it is an implementation of some (most?) of the
major new features, in a preliminary version based on various working
papers, and not the final standard.

(FWIW: I don't think any compiler fully implements all of C++11, but I'd
love to be proven wrong.)

Comment: As of this writing, no compiler fully implements C++11. However, the latest trunks of [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) and [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) do implement very similar subsets thereof. So if you ignore inheriting constructors, alignment, and C++11 attributes, as well as many of the threading language changes, you should be fine. Well, between those two compilers.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling through here, this answer is out of date. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/which-c-standard-is-the-default-when-compiling-with-g

Answer (score 14):

You can find out your compiler version like this:

```
g++ --version
```

That doesn't tell you if you are using c++11. To use c++11 features, you would have to call the compiler with thr `-std=c++0x` flag:

```
g++ -std=c++0x ....
```

Bear in mind that gcc doesn't implement 100% of c++11 yet, and how much it implements depends on the version. See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) for a table of supported features.

**EDIT**: strictly speaking, if you are using GCC you cannot be using a fully compliant c++11 compiler due to the missing features. But versions 4.6.1 onwards cover a great deal of the standard.

Answer (score 6):

If you're in linux, checking the version is easy.

```
> gcc --version
```

Will tell you the version you have. Note that GCC C++11 support is incomplete still, you can find the details here: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

I've used a few C++11 features myself, namely initializer lists, and the `nullptr` constant. I'm using GCC 4.6 and it's working fine.

edit: And yes, as @jaunchopanza said, you'll need the `-std=c++0x` compiler flag to make it work. If you're using Code::Blocks, just right-click on your project, choose *Build options...*, and check the item that says *Have g++ follow the coming C++0x ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++0x]*