# Which C++ standard is the default when compiling with g++?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I have a piece of code that looks like the following. Let's say it's in a file named `example.cpp`

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string> // line added after edit for clarity

int main() {
    std::string filename = "input.txt";
    std::ifstream in(filename);

    return 0;
}
```

On a windows, if I type in the `cmd` the command `g++ example.cpp`, it will fail. It's a long list of errors I think mostly due to the linker complaining about not being able to convert from `string` to `const char*`.

But if I run the compiler using an additional argument like so: `g++ -std=c++17 example.cpp`, it will compile and work fine with no problems.

What happens when I run the former command? I'm guessing a default <s>version</s> standard of the C++ compiler gets called, but I don't know which? And as a programmer/developer, should I always use the latter command with the extra argument?

Comment: Depends on your gcc version.

Answer (score 129):

If your version of `g++` is later than 4.7 I think you can find the default version of C++ standard supported like so:

```
g++ -dM -E -x c++  /dev/null | grep -F __cplusplus
```

An example from my machine:

```
mburr@mint17 ~ $ g++ --version | head -1
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
mburr@mint17 ~ $ g++ -dM -E -x c++  /dev/null | grep -F __cplusplus
#define __cplusplus 199711L
```

Some references:

- [Details on the `g++` options used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27980787/12711)
- [Why this only works for `g++` 4.7 or later](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1773)

Comment: That seem to do it! My 1p worth ... when you do specify  `-std=...` option, it does change the value.

Comment: @Michael, please add the link where the cplusplus results are matched with the standard:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: It works for me, resulting in `#define __cplusplus 201402L`.

Comment: Great. As one might expect, it also works for clang and C: `clang -dM -E -x c  /dev/null | grep -F __STDC_VERSION__`

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari For an explanation of `__cplusplus`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053960/how-are-the-cplusplus-directive-defined-in-various-compilers could be helpful.

Answer (score 33):

g++  man page actually tells what is the default standard for C++ code.

Use following script to show the relevant part:

```
man g++ | col -b | grep -B 2 -e '-std=.* This is the default'
```

For example, in RHEL 6 g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23), the output:

```
         gnu++98
           GNU dialect of -std=c++98.  This is the default for C++ code.
```

And in Fedora 28 g++ (GCC) 8.1.1 20180502 (Red Hat 8.1.1-1), the output:

```
       gnu++14
       gnu++1y
           GNU dialect of -std=c++14.  This is the default for C++ code.  The name gnu++1y is deprecated.
```

Comment: This relies on consistency between `gcc` and its documentation,  which is not valid for g++ 12.2.1. The manpage says the default is C++17, but the reality is C++20.

Answer (score 27):

You can also check with gdb

1. `$ g++ example.cpp -g` Compile program with -g flag to generate debug info
2. `$ gdb a.out` Debug program with gdb
3. `(gdb) b main` Put a breakpoint at main
4. `(gdb) run` Run program (will pause at breakpoint)
5. `(gdb) info source`

Prints out something like:

```
Current source file is example.cpp
Compilation directory is /home/xxx/cpp
Located in /home/xxx/cpp/example.cpp
Contains 7 lines.
Source language is c++.
Producer is GNU C++14 6.3.0 20170516 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g.
Compiled with DWARF 2 debugging format.
Does not include preprocessor macro info.
```

There is the standard used by compiler: `Producer is GNU C++14`

If you recompile your program using `-std=c++11` (for example), gdb detects it: 
`Producer is GNU C++11`

Answer (score 17):

I believe that it is possible to tell by looking at the man page (at least for g++):

Under the description of `-std`, the man page lists all C++ standards, including the GNU dialects. Under one specific standard, it is rather inconspicuously stated, `This is the default for C++ code.` (there is an analogous statement for C standards: `This is the default for C code.`).

For instance, for `g++/gcc version 5.4.0`, this is listed under `gnu++98/gnu++03`, whereas for `g++/gcc version 6.4.0`, this is listed under `gnu++14`.

Answer (score 16):

> I'm guessing a default version of the C++ compiler gets called, but I don't know which?

This is only guessable by reading the documentation of your particular compiler version.

If using a *recent* [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), I recommend first to understand what version are you using by running

```
g++ -v
```

or

```
g++ --version
```

and then refer to the version of the particular release of GCC. For example for GCC 7, read [GCC 7 changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) etc

Alternatively, run

```
g++ -dumpspecs
```

and decipher the default so called [spec file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Spec-Files.html).

BTW, you could ensure (e.g. in some of your common header file) that C++ is at least C++17 by coding

```
 #if __cplusplus < 201412L
 #error expecting C++17 standard
 #endif
```

and I actually recommend doing it that way.

PS. Actually, think of C++98 & C++17 being two *different* languages (e.g. like Ocaml4 and C++11 are). Require your user to have a compiler supporting some defined language standard (e.g. C++11), not some particular version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Read also about [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

Comment: Which part of your quoted [GCC 7 changes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/changes.html) mentions which -std=xxx option is the default if -std=xxx is not specified?

Comment: Each version of the GCC compiler documentation explicitly states the default language standard for both C and C++.  No guessing required.  See my answer, below.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the GCC compiler, you can find it on the man pages:

`man g++ | grep "This is the default for C++ code"`

Answer (score 6):

Typing `g++ --version` in your command shell will reveal the version of the compiler, and from that you can infer the default standard. So you can't tell directly but you can *infer* it, with some effort.

Compilers are *supposed* to `#define` `__cplusplus` which can be used to extract the standard that they purport to implement at compile time; but many don't do this yet.

(And don't forget to include all the C++ standard library headers you need: where is the one for `std::string` for example? Don't rely on your C++ standard library implementation including other headers automatically - in doing that you are not writing portable C++.)

Comment: Wrong since `g++ --version` shows only the version of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, not of the default standard.

Comment: I think std::string is included in <fstream>. Using strings works fine for me when I include only the fstream library

Comment: @Manuel You shouldn't rely on that. Always `#include` what you are using from the standard library.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch doesn't default standard depend directly on the compiler version?

Comment: Yes, but there is that additional indirection

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, that's been noted. On another note, typing g++ --version just tells me the version of g++. It doesn't say what default "-std=c++" it's using

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Oh, yes. Haven't notice this miswording of an answer, you're right.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was obvious that `--version` didn't return the standard used directly. Have stated the obvious now ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Your code will compile with any compilers (and associated libraries) compliant with C++11 and later.

The reason is that C++11 introduced a `std::ifstream` constructor that accepts a `const std::string &`.   Before C++11, a `std::string` could not be passed, and it would be necessary in your code to pass `filename.c_str()` rather than `filename`.

According to information from gnu, https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11, gcc.4.8.1 was the first version to fully support C++11.   At the command line `g++ -v` will prod `g++` to telling you its version number.

If you dig into documentation, you might be able to find the version/subversion that first supported enough features so your code - as given - would compile.   But such a version would support some C++11 features and not others.

Since windows isn't distributed with g++, you will have whatever version someone (you?) has chosen to install.   There will be no default version of g++ associated with your version of windows.

Comment: This is true, but is more a long and useful comment than a real answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

The default language standards for both C and C++ are specified in the GCC Manuals.  You can find these as follows:

Browse to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/

Select the **GCC #.## Manual** link for the version of GCC you are interested in, e.g. for GCC 7.5.0:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.5.0/gcc/

Click the topic link **Language Standards Supported by GCC**, followed by the topic **C++ Language** (or **C language**).  Either of these topics will have a sentence such as:

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu++14.
>
> The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu11.

The above two examples are for GCC 7.5.0.

Answer (score 2):

> What happens when I run the former command? I'm guessing a default version standard of the C++ compiler gets called, but I don't know which?

When you run `g++` without specifying a C++ language standard to use, it will use whichever one was decided to be the default when none is specified.

The default C++ language standard used by GCC depends on the version of GCC you're using. See [GCC's C++ language support status documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html), which at the time of this writing states (emphasis added):

> **C++17 mode is the default since GCC 11**; it can be explicitly selected with the -std=c++17 command-line flag, or -std=gnu++17 to enable GNU extensions as well. Some C++17 features are available since GCC 5, but support was experimental and the ABI of C++17 features was not stable until GCC 9.

> GCC has full support for the of **the 2014 C++ standard**. This mode **is the default in GCC 6.1 up until GCC 10 (inclusive)**; it can be explicitly selected with the -std=c++14 command-line flag, or -std=gnu++14 to enable GNU extensions as well.

> GCC has full support for **the 1998 C++ standard** as modified by the 2003 technical corrigendum and some later defect reports, excluding the export feature which was later removed from the language. This mode **is the default in GCC versions prior to 6.1**; it can be explicitly selected with the -std=c++98 command-line flag, or -std=gnu++98 to enable GNU extensions as well.

If you're interested in language / standard library support for other compilers as well, you can see [Clang's C++ support documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) or [cppreference.com's compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

---

> And as a programmer/developer, should I always use the latter command with the extra argument?

If you're working alone on a project and only working with one specific compiler and one specific version of it, do whatever you want. But if you're working with multiple compilers / versions, or working with other people who might, or working on a project with users who might, (Ex. if you are writing a library) then you should probably be specifying language standard requirements in the build configuration of whatever build system you are using (Ex. CMake's [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html)).