# Do I still have to link -std=c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have clang++ 12, clang++ 13 and g++ 10.3.0 compilers.  I have noticed that I can compile c++11 features like `auto` and raw string literals without specifically linking `-std=c++11`. Is this a default option and if so, how can I found out which standard is included by default?

Comment: Dupe?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/

Comment: also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980383/