# I encoutered a problem when I used mt19937 to generate random numbers in C++

Tags: c++, random

I was trying the generate random numbers using `mt19937` in c++ as shown in the code but I encounterd some weired behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    mt19937 rng((unsigned int) chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    int n = rng() % 10 + 2;
    cout << n << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x = rng() % 10 + 1;
        int y = rng() % 10 + 1;
        cout << x << " " << y << " " << endl;
    }
}
```

When I run my code in "CLion", [It runs and behaves as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hug6J.png);however, when trying to run the code using the terminal, It doesn't compile and I recieve `'mt19937' was not declared in this scope`  as an error message.
[Here is the Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wCYF.png)

**Update 1**

I removed the `#include <bits/stdc++. h>` from the code but the code still doesn't compile from terminal

**Update 2**

I have been using *Mingw* version which comes with *[Codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)*
so I uninstalled it and redownloaded Mingw from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/mailman/mingw-w64-public/thread/68783.73057.qm%40web34301.mail.mud.yahoo.com/).
Surprisingly, the problem is now solved and I could run the code from the terminal.

**Update 3**

Now when I compile some program using the command `g++ <name>.cpp` , a file named
`a.exe` is created. I don't know why its name is always `a.exe` regardless of the name of the original cpp file.
In order to name the `.exe` file the same as the cpp file, I have to write
`g++ <name>.cpp -o <name>`.
Can anyone help explain why the name is always `a.cpp` ??

Comment: What version of GCC are you using when building from the terminal?

Comment: Did you try including the correct header `<random>`?

Comment: Also please copy-paste text *as text* into your question, including build errors and console input/output. And please [don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>    using namespace std;` is a terrible habit, no wonder you are running into trouble.

Comment: My gcc version is  `(i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0` .
I tried to remve `<bits/stdc++.h>`  and include the necessary libraries but the problem didn't change

Comment: Please update the question with your last version that still doesn't work.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Add the full build commend you're using to the question and type `g++ -v` on the command line to be absolutely certain you don't have an older g++ lurking earlier in the path.

Comment: See the question/answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories for a method to list g++'s default include directories. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/which-c-standard-is-the-default-when-compiling-with-g for a question/answer on how to see which default c++ version your compiler uses. Please tell us both.

Comment: "Update 3" is a totally different and separate question. It is the default behavior though, and is well-documented.