# C++ Union Curly Bracket Initinitializer: "error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers"

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and read about curly bracket initializer which is available in C++ 11. I try to create a simple union which looks like this

```
union UExample {

  UExample(const uint12_t value = 0) : raw{value} {}

  uint12_t raw;

};
```

When I try to compile the file I get this error

```
./stack.h:18:57: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
  UBankedAddress(const uint12_t value = 0) : raw{value} {}
                                                        ^
./stack.h:18:49: error: expected '('
  UBankedAddress(const uint12_t value = 0) : raw{value} {}
                                                ^
./stack.h:18:55: error: expected ';' after expression
  UBankedAddress(const uint12_t value = 0) : raw{value} {}
```

Dose anyone has an idea to solve this?

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: You declared a `union` but it looks like you are trying to give it a `class` constructor?

Comment: Compiles for me - live - https://godbolt.org/z/rd66K5n9f  Looks like it could be an error on the previous (not shown) line.

Comment: Your error message does not match the code provided.  Please give use a [mre] and the matching error.

Comment: @NathanOliver I stand corrected: `A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual functions.` I haven't used unions in decades so was out of practice. (Personally, I don't like them.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. It relates to the `g++` compiler on MacOS. `clang++` should be used instead.

**Before (not working):**

```
g++ stack.cpp -o stack
```

**After (working):**

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ stack.cpp -o stack
```

Comment: What happens if you pass `-std=c++11` to `g++` ?

Comment: Then probably your installation of  `g++` is old and is defaulting to a pre C++11 standard. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/which-c-standard-is-the-default-when-compiling-with-g

Comment: Your code is valid C++11, but not valid C++98.  That's the issue.  You were using a very old C++ standard.

Comment: That  is interesting. I have a new MacBook from late 2020. Did not think that Apple delivers with such old versions preinstalled :D