# How to initialize an array of structures without using compound literals but still in one line in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
struct StudentStruct {
  char name[32];
  float score;
};
```

and it is initialized this way:

```
  StudentStruct students[1000];
  for (size_t i = 1; i < sizeof(students) / sizeof(students[0]) - 5; ++i) {
    Ops[i] = (StudentStruct){"Empty", 0.0};
  }
  students[  0] = (StudentStruct){"Alex",    78.9};
  // There will always be a huge gap, which could prevent some
  // possible syntax to work
  students[995] = (StudentStruct){"Bob",     3.14};
  students[996] = (StudentStruct){"Charlie", 2.71};
  students[997] = (StudentStruct){"David",   99.9};
  students[998] = (StudentStruct){"Eugene",  0   };
  students[999] = (StudentStruct){"Frank",   -2.2};
  // This is just an example, in reality I would need to manually define hundreds of them.
```

This works well until I enabled `-Wpedantic` which complains that `warning: ISO C++ forbids compound-literals [-Wpedantic]`. I am wondering if there is a ISO C++-compliant way that does something very similar.

I am aware of the following:

1. [brace initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/initializing-classes-and-structs-without-constructors-cpp?view=msvc-170): but after playing for a while it seems to me that it can't fit into my case.
2. change `struct` to `class` and prepare a constructor: this should work, but I would prefer keeping `struct` if possible because the code may potentially be called in other languages, have a simple memory layout makes me feel a little bit better.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

- Some answers point to this:

```
students[0] = { "Alex",    78.9 };
```

I am not sure why, it doesn't work with my g++, the error is:
`error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘StudentStruct’ and ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’)`

- I am using `g++ 10.2.1` and using the method in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734397/which-c-standard-is-the-default-when-compiling-with-g), the default C++ standard is C++14.

Comment: You can add constructors to a `struct` just fine, so do that.

Comment: Try `students[0] = { "Alex",    78.9 };` , etc. I just tested it, and it does match the standard.

Comment: Try changing all of your usage of `(StudentStruct){"value", value}` to `StudentStruct{"value", value}`

Comment: What version of g++ do you have and what version of C++ are you compiling against?

Comment: @NathanOliver it is g++ 10.2.1, I also added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the parens around the type name. Why would you need it?

```
students[  0] = StudentStruct{"Alex",    78.9};
```

Or you can remove the type name completely in this context:

```
students[  0] = {"Alex",    78.9};
```

Comment: Hi, I just tested, seems `students[  0] = StudentStruct{"Alex",    78.9};` works but `students[  0] = {"Alex",    78.9};` doesnt. Btw, do you know if the 1st approach has any name? Some fancy ones just like "brace initialization"?

Comment: Both options should work. Maybe you have an outdated compiler?
https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jYdP1KEPK

Comment: 1st option - not sure about the _exact_ name, this stuff is complicated in c++, but it does aggregate initialization here

Comment: I added my compiler info to the question (g++ 10.2.1), it doesn't work online either: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nnPzq3ce4

Comment: @D.J.Elkind It is a bug.  Version 11 and up all compile the code.

Comment: oh really? I use `g++ 10.2.1` because it ships with Debian's stable version. So I did not pay much attention in this regard prior to this question.

Comment: With C++ it is really important to keep your compilers up to date. A lot of bugs get fixed and a lot of missing features are added every release. Usually once you see a problem like this, it is a good reason to update the compiler.