What is a proper way to initialize object on stack or on heap?
tl;dr; What is a proper way to initialize object on stack or on heap?
I want to make a profiling tool that can track time for iterative purposes and for single measurements - so that I can use same object to measure average time for single function (called N times) but also to see how functions behave in complex project.
Now, I might be wrong, but the way I see it this object needs to be able to be initialized with reference (if there is global tracker) and independently on heap ( if its one use). I tried to mangle something that could work as MRE, so please consider this code:
struct test{
    
    test(const char *caller, int l )
    :caller(caller),line(l),pntr(nullptr),flag(0)
    {
        std::clog << "instantiated as heap" << std::endl;
        this->make_heap();
    }
    
    test(const test & other)
    {
        std::clog << "copying\t";
        this->caller = other.caller;
        this->line = other.line;
        if( other.is_as_referenece())
        {
            std::clog << "as reference\n";
            this->pntr = other.pntr; // multiple pointers to same variable??
            this->flag = other.flag;
        }
        else
        {
            std::clog << "as heap\n";
            this->pntr = new unsigned(*other.pntr);
            this->flag = other.flag;
        }
    }
    
    test( test && other)
    {
        std::clog << "moving\t";
        this->caller = other.caller;
        this->line = other.line;
        other.caller = "\0"; // moved, thus no caller 
        other.line = 0; // moved, thus no line number
        
        if( other.is_as_referenece())
        {
            std::clog << "as reference\n";
            this->pntr = other.pntr;
            this->flag = other.flag;
            other.unlink_reference();
        }
        else
        {
            std::clog << "as heap\n";
            this->pntr = new unsigned(*other.pntr);
            this->flag = other.flag;
            other.delete_heap();
        }
        
    }
    
    operator bool() { return this->line != 0;} // no line number 0 
    
    test &operator=(const test &other)
    {
        std::clog << "copying\t";
        this->caller = other.caller;
        this->line = other.line;
        if( other.is_as_referenece()) 
        {
            std::clog << "as reference\n";
            this->pntr = other.pntr; // not quite sure about this, 
            this->flag = other.flag;
        }
        else
        {
            std::clog << "as heap\n";
            this->pntr = new unsigned(*other.pntr);
            this->flag = other.flag;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    test &operator=( test && other)
    {
        std::clog << "moving\t";
        this->caller = other.caller;
        this->line = other.line;
        other.caller = "\0";
        other.line = -1;
        
        if( other.is_as_referenece()) // if other is referenced, swap pointers 
        {
            std::clog << "as reference\n";
            this->pntr = other.pntr;
            this->flag = other.flag;
            other.unlink_reference();
        }
        else // if others is heap allocated, make a new heap copy
        {
            std::clog << "as heap\n";
            this->pntr = new unsigned(*other.pntr);
            this->flag = other.flag;
            other.delete_heap();
        }
        return *this;
    }
    test &operator=( unsigned &ref) // normally it generates heap, unless by operator reference is assigned 
    {
        if( this->is_on_heap()) // checks if its heap allocated
        {
            this->delete_heap(); // if is, deletes heap 
        }
        this->link_reference(ref);
        return *this;
    }
    
    ~test()
    {
        std::clog << "deletion proccess" << std::endl;
        if(this->pntr != nullptr) // if not pointing to NULL 
        {
            if(!this->delete_heap()) // try to delete heap, 
            {
                this->unlink_reference(); // if fails, unlink object 
            }
        }    
        
    }
    
    const char *caller; // function name 
    unsigned line; // line number timer is called from 
    
    bool is_on_heap() const // state informers 
    {
        return (flag & 0x1) == 0x1;
    }
    
    bool is_as_referenece() const // state informers 
    {
        return (flag & 0x2) == 0x2;
    }
    
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const test &); // for testing purposes 
    
    protected:
        
        bool link_reference(unsigned &value) // links object that is reffered
        {
            if( this->is_on_heap()) {return false;}
            std::cout << "linking reference" << std::endl;
            this->pntr = &value;
            this->set_as_reff();
            return true;
        }
        
        bool unlink_reference() // unlinks object that is reffered
        {
            if( this->is_on_heap()) {return false;}
            std::cout << "unlinking reference" << std::endl;
            this->pntr = nullptr;
            this->clear_as_reff();
            return true;
        }
        
        bool make_heap()  // makes object on heap
        {
            if( this->is_as_referenece() ) { return false;}
            std::cout << "making heap" << std::endl;
            this->pntr = new unsigned(0);
            this->set_as_heap();
            return true;
        }
        
        bool delete_heap() // deletes object if its on heap
        {
            if( this->is_as_referenece() ) {return false;}
            std::cout << "deleting heap" << std::endl;
            delete this->pntr;
            this->pntr = nullptr;
            this->clear_on_heap();
            return true;
        }
        
    private:
        unsigned *pntr = nullptr;   // main data holder.
        uint8_t flag = 0;       // state holder, tracks if object is on heap or reference
        
        // main state changers 
        void set_as_heap()    { flag |= 0x1;}
        void clear_on_heap()    { flag &= 0xfe;}
        void set_as_reff()    { flag |= 0x2;}
        void clear_as_reff()    { flag &= 0xfd;}
            
    
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const test &t)
{
    
    if( t.pntr == nullptr)
    {
        return os << "NOT THERE" << '\t' << t.line << ':' << t.caller;
    }    
    
    if( t.is_as_referenece())
    {
        os << "REFF: " << t.pntr << ' ' << *t.pntr; 
    }
    else
    {
        os << "HEAP: "<< t.pntr << ' ' << *t.pntr; 
    }
    return os << '\t' << t.line << ':' << t.caller;
}

#define TESTER_HEAP test temp = test(__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);

Where to gain function call and line (for g++ (C++11.4), Ubuntu) I need a macro to initialize it to correctly place in source. Now with scope testing, valgrind and gdb have no issues:
void test_macro()
{
    unsigned value = 123;    
    
    {
    TESTER_HEAP
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    {
    TESTER_HEAP
    temp = value;
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    {
    TESTER_HEAP;
    test temp2 = temp;
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;    
    std::cout << temp2 << std::endl;
    }
    
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    {
    TESTER_HEAP;
    test temp2 = (test &&)temp;
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;    
    std::cout << temp2 << std::endl;
    }
}

I tried googling this and it is possible that due to some terminology i simply wasn't searching for right things since search was unhelpful. I am sure there are plethora of people who are more experienced and smarter than me who had tried something similar. So can kind people of SE help by pointing to right direction or sharing how they approached heap and stack allocation within same object?

Off topic: since C++11/14 explicit use of operator new and delete is fishy. It is recommended to use containers and smart pointers (by using std::make_unique and std::make_shared)

can you use C++20?

@MarekR yes, I could update my compiler. This, however, isn't production build, I need this to work on my computer and it alone. C++11.4 came with OS, and so far it works. I see the benefits of updating to newer version, I just think that it would stop me to figure out solutions implemented in newer versions that fix last one.

There is no such thing as "C++11.4". You probably confuse gcc (g++) versions with language standard versions. Gnu's C++ compiler version 11.4 does support C++20. See this table for details on which compilers and which versions support what features.

Also there are many way to initialize an object in C++. What do you mean by proper way. The question is too broad as well as unclear and needs more focus. There is no universal way to will work for everything. It all depends on the situation/context.

@heapunderrun fair enough, changed tag to default version of c++17 based on check from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51396583/3142882](this answer) and console output.

@user12002570 both context and situation are explained within post. You are free to read it, or not - at your own discretion.

@Danilo In your tldr you asked "What is a proper way to initialize object on stack or on heap?" which has no "proper" answer in c++. Also the question doesn't make sense.

Yeah, because its a title. I can't write enough context and information within 150 char, see this post

(user changed "title" to "tl;dr") In this case, there is a body of the post for information as context and situation.

@MarekR The OP isn't explicitly using operator new and delete. The are using new and delete expressions. The compiler will do the necessary so that a new expression causes operator new to be called followed by any required constructor. Similarly a delete expression will result in a call to the destructor followed by a call to operator delete.
