# C++ version 98 in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to get the C++ version I'm using, which I assumed was an easy task as developers need the version number to see which functionality is available (or is that a wrong assumption)?
I tried the advised method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7132549/1667868):

```
auto someversion = __cplusplus;
std::cout << someversion;
```

which shows:

> 199711

According to the linked answer that means im using C++98.
Is this correct or is there another method to get the right version number?

I also tried running the [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026195/1667868):

```
g++ --version
```

But the command did not run (Command "g++" is not valid.).
How do I find out which C++ version I am running?

edit: context

*So how does one see which functionality is available or do you just need to try and find out? I'm trying async but when i copy the example my syntax is not valid, thats when I checked for the version number to see if the syntax from the example was useable with my setup. (the [example](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial) :  )*

Comment: The C++ standard version is a "compiler thing", not a runtime value. Also a compiler may not support all features of a given standard, so such a value wouldn't be able to inform you of everything

Comment: You're never really using a specific version because none of them are fully implemented (yet). In the case of other compilers, they remain partially implemented for quite a while. To be more reliable, *features* need to be checked for, not versions.

Comment: Visual C++ and g++ are two different compilers. Unclear what the question is.

Comment: `g++` is the [GCC (GNU Compiler Collection)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) frontend or driver program for C++, which doesn't come with Visual Studio. The Microsoft Visual C++ frontend program is called `cl`.

Comment: it's complicated with Visual C++ because they don't yet implement all of C++98 (that's still in C++17) so they refuse to update that until they do.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, so how does one see which functionality is available or do you just need to try and find out? I'm trying async but when i copy the example my syntax is not valid, thats when i checked for the version number. (the example : https://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/10/17/cpp-11-async-tutorial/ )

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart there is a compiler flag you'll need to [enable for coroutines](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/04/29/more-about-resumable-functions-in-c/)

Comment: @Mgetz nothing in the link he provided uses coroutines, it's just plain C++11 std::async which is supported just fine in VS2017

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart, There are nice [tables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) that work well if you know which compilers you plan to support/use.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart> I'd say usually it's the other way around: first you define your needs, and then choose a tool that matches those needs. Only if you then find none exists you might lower your expectations. (as for compilers you'll find most support different dialects of the language and you need to specify which you want to use)

Comment: @Ron I tried to implement some examples (see comment above) but my syntax was not valid, i tried finding out if i was using a c++ version which supports the syntax i was trying but i could not find the vesion. comments showed version of c++ dosnt mather. I still dont know how to find out how i can check if i can use some syntax like "std::future<void> result( std::async(called_from_async));" from the example.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart> you need to configure your compiler. I don't know VC++, but for instance with gcc you tell it when you invoke it which version of the language you want. Say, `gcc -std=c++11` or `gcc -std=c++14` or ... if you don't, your compiler will pick one for you.

Comment: VS2017 in particular has a setting `/std:c++latest` which enables as much support as it has for new features.

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
cl
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.40629 for x86
```

Then, see [Visual C++ Language Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance) to check exactly which features are supported by your compiler.